# Calculating a conditional expectation

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Suppose that $X$ follows a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha > 0$, $\beta > 0$. I want to calculate
$$\frac{\int_c^1 x f(x) dx}{P(X \geq c)} - \frac{\int_0^c x f(x) dx}{P(X \leq c)}$$

for some constant $c \in (0, 1)$.

I have tried the following code. While it works in the $\alpha = \beta = 1$ case, it seems won't run (at least in a reasonable amount of time) in other cases. What am I doing wrong? The code is below:

```
less[c_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 Integrate[x PDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], x], {x, 0, c}]/
  CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], c]

more[c_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 Integrate[
   x PDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], x], {x, c, 1}]/(1 - 
    CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], c])

diff[c_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 more[c, \[Alpha], \[Beta]] - less[c, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]

Plot[diff[c, 0.5, 0.5], {c, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: I think that you can calculate all the integrals in closed form; that might help with performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist = BetaDistribution[α, β];

dpa = DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist]

(* α > 0 && β > 0 *)

DistributionDomain[dist]

(* Interval[{0, 1}] *)
```

Integrals are generally faster and simpler when given the appropriate assumptions.

```
less[c_, α_, β_] = Assuming[dpa && 0 < c < 1,
  Integrate[x PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, c}]/CDF[dist, c] // Simplify]

(* Beta[c, 1 + α, β]/(
Beta[α, β] BetaRegularized[c, α, β]) *)

more[c_, α_, β_] = Assuming[dpa && 0 < c < 1,
  Integrate[x PDF[dist, x], {x, c, 1}]/(1 - CDF[dist, c]) // Simplify]

(* (-Gamma[1 + α] Gamma[β] + 
   Beta[c, 1 + α, β] Gamma[
     1 + α + β])/(Beta[α, β] (-1 + 
     BetaRegularized[c, α, β]) Gamma[
    1 + α + β]) *)
```

**EDIT:** Use `FunctionExpand`

```
diff[c_, α_, β_] = Assuming[dpa && 0 < c < 1,
  more[c, α, β] - less[c, α, β] // 
   FunctionExpand // FullSimplify]

(* ((1 - c)^β c^α Gamma[α] \
Gamma[β])/((α + β) Beta[
     c, α, β] Gamma[α] Gamma[β] - 
   Beta[c, α, β]^2 Gamma[1 + α + β]) *)

Plot[diff[c, 0.5, 0.5], {c, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Or more simply,

```
p[c_, α_, β_] = Assuming[0 < c < 1,
  Expectation[x \[Conditioned] x >= c, x \[Distributed] dist] -
    Expectation[x \[Conditioned] x < c, x \[Distributed] dist] // 
   FullSimplify]

(* ((1 - c)^β c^α Gamma[α] Gamma[β])/((α + \
β) Beta[c, α, β] Gamma[α] Gamma[β] - 
   Beta[c, α, β]^2 Gamma[1 + α + β]) *)

diff[c, α, β] === p[c, α, β]]

(* True *)
```